# RewriteRule rule in .htaccess for matching keyword

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to make a 301 redirect from

```
https://www.example.net/sub1/specific_keyword/page1/page2
https://www.example.net/sub2/sub3/specific_keyword/page3/page4
https://www.example.net/specific_keyword/page5/page6
```

to

```
https://www.example.net/sub1/
https://www.example.net/sub2/sub3/
https://www.example.net/
```

I tried this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/specific_keyword$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.net\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

But no luck.

Comment: Do you have any other htaccess rules apart from shown ones?

Comment: RewriteCond only works on RewriteRule, RedirectMatch is not even supplied by the same Apache module as the two first ones.

Comment: With your RewriteRule attempt, you demanded that the requested URL _ends_ with `/folder-to-remove`, via the `$` at the end, so that won’t match.

Comment: @CBroe RedirectMatch is working, RewriteRule is not. How can I restrict RedirectMatch to only apply to example.net?

Comment: Why not just _make_ the RewriteRule version work, I just told you what’s wrong with it, didn’t I? To achieve the same thing using RedirectMatch, you’d have to look into phrasing an appropriate condition within an `<If>` block, and put the RedirectMatch directive in there.

Comment: Removing the `$` at the end of the RewriteRule attempt worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> With your RewriteRule attempt, you demanded that the requested URL
> ends with /folder-to-remove, via the $ at the end, so that won’t match (Source: #comment120998408_68464303)

With that fixed, place following rules at top of your htaccess Rules file. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs or use a redirect checker online.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/.*$ $1/$2? [R=301,NE,L]
```

***OR*** only match the specific keyword

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)specific_keyword/ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Where are you removing the "folder-to-remove"?

Comment: @Mau, this regex `^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/.*$` catches 1st 2 values eg: `/sub1/sub2` in capturing groups and `.*` matches everything till end of uri value. In case you want to look for specific values matches then try like: `^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/folder-to-remove/page-to-remove/` but I believe these are just examples shown by you so `.*` will help but in case you want to specify very generic string to be matched place it there eg: `^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/bla/bla/test123$` like that and it will match that, let me know if you have any queries here, cheers.

Comment: the sub1/sub2 are random, can be anything. 
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.net$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.net\/$1" [R=301,L]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.net [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)\/specific_keyword\/ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.net\/$1" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>` 
The above works, I needed to add extra lines for www check

Comment: @Mau, Sure, thanks for letting know here, just an addiotnal info if you always have 2 levels eg: `/sub1/sub2/specific_keyword` then rule `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/.*$ $1/$2? [R=301,NE,L]` will be Good to get 2 levels into 2 different parameters OR if you want to catch everything before specific word in uri in single capturing group which you are doing right now then we can do it, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: @Mau, sure I made necessary changes now, even we need not to escape `:` or `/` or `.` on right side of url rewriting. Cheers and happy learning.

Comment: please make sure that the redirect to the root domain is also working: `https://www.example.net/specific_keyword/page5/page6`